# Bootstrap 4 Align margins of separate objects

Tags: html, css, alignment, bootstrap-4

I've run into an issue that I can't seem wrap my head around.
Using Bootstrap 4 and HTML and I'm not that good at CSS or CSS3, this is my first undertaking of getting things to align or following a design that was handed from a designer and put it to html and css.

I need to align the ending of one row or container with the right margin of the upper slider and i need to do the same for the second row or container except align it with the opposite margin of the upper slider.

To better explain please refer to the image.
[image]
I need the image that is in those rows or containers to be responsive and grow as the row or container grows and stop till it reaches about the red lines.

Here's my code so far:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="slider20" class="rev_slider" style="width:100%;">
                <ul style="padding-left: 0px;"> 
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h1 class="jumbo-text">some text</h1>
                    </div>
                    <li data-transition="slideleft" data-slotamount="1" data-thumb="/*/img5_thumb.jpg"> 
                        <img src="assets/images/background.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:100%;"> 
                    </li>                         
                </ul>                     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-nowrap align-items-start align-content-start d-flex flex-row-reverse justify-content-start container-fluid" style="padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;">
        <div class="row ml-auto">
            <img src="assets/images/elipseleft1.png" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to post the code you've attempted.

Comment: @ZimSystem I have followed up with my html code.